# Reload background pic every 5 secs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I need to reload the background picture every 5 seconds pulling the img-url from a php file. Something like this:

PHP (I know how to do the php part):

```
<?
//mysql connection
//mysql query
echo ('$picurl')
?>
```

HTML:

```
<td height="282" style= "background:url(img/frontpage/johana.jpg) no-repeat">

<-- html content -->

</td>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Whit jquery you use:

```
setInterval(function() {
      // Do something every 2 seconds
}, 2000);
```

on setinterval Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request of your php page and use the result
for set with http://api.jquery.com/css/ the css of the page.

Comment: Fixed with this thanks

Answer (score 1):

Untested but should do the trick (using JQuery):

```
   setInterval(fetchImage(), 5000);

    function fetchImage() {

        $.get("/path/to/your.php", function(data){ // "data" is whatever your php script returns
            //console.log(data); // for debugging your php response
            var imageString = 'url(' + data + ') no-repeat'; // Build your background css string
            $('td#yourID').css('background',imageString); // assign the value of imageString to the td's background css property
        });

    }
```

Your php file must return a single image path.

Comment: Hi, it show the first imagen pull from the php file.. but it won't load any more back grounds :-(

Comment: Uncomment the `console.log(data);` line above and see what happens in the console. Do you see the same image path printed repeatedly? Or any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help: Edit: Try This One :D

```
<script>
        var slideShowNum = 0;
        var slideShowSources = ["<? echo ('$picurl') ?>", "<? echo ('$picur2') ?>", "<? echo ('$picur3') ?>", "<? echo ('$picur4') ?>"];

        function SlideShowImageChanger() {

            slideShowNum++;
            if (slideShowNum == 4) {
                slideShowNum = 0;
            }

            var imageSrc = slideShowSources[slideShowNum];


            var imageElm = document.getElementById('YourTdId');
            imageElm.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imageSrc + ")";
        }
</script>


<td height="282" id="YourTdId" style= "background:url(img/frontpage/johana.jpg) no-repeat">

<-- html content -->

</td> 

<script>
setInterval(SlideShowImageChanger, 8000);
</script>
```

Comment: OP wants the images to come from a PHP script

Answer (score 0):

Give the TD an ID or class you can target, then something like this will get you on your way:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/server/script.php',
        success: function(response) {
            // This assumes the output of your server script is simply
            // an image url
            $('#td-id').css('background-image', response);
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Hi, it show the first imagen pull from the php file.. but it won't load any more back grounds.

Comment: Add a `console.log('fetching image');` before the ajax request and make sure you're not getting any errors.  What is the output of your PHP script? Check in the network tab to make sure the request is actually going out and hit the URL in a new tab to make sure that the output matches what you expect it should.